# Reboot from windows to linux with grub

Tags: windows, linux, grub, reboot

I have machine with Windows and Linux with GRUB, only with remote access. Is there any way to chage default OS in grub from windows? I know how to achieve it from linux, something like

echo "savedefault --default=2 --once" | grub --batch; sudo reboot

should work.

Is there any way to achieve it from windows?

Comment: Guess not possible from windows

Comment: you might look into [Grub4DOS](http://grub4dos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which can be installed onto FAT32/NTFS drives.  then *grub-set-default* or your *savedefault* commandline could work.

Comment: Just wanted to link my question, since its same question name, but your question is changing default entry, I want to change just "one time". http://superuser.com/questions/1004199/reboot-from-windows-to-linux-with-grub-reboot-but-something-cmd-accepts Sorry I can't comment, so I answered.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers - Why are you submitting an answer to this question if you don't have an answer to this question?  On what world do you think that is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to install [`Ext2 IFS Drivers`](http://www.fs-driver.org/) and access `menu.lst` files from windows and change it. This solution works only for Ext2 file system

Comment: well.... sorta.  (1) this only works for Grub1; (2) the only thing you can change in *menu.lst* is the default entry; (3) instead, you'd want to use *grub-set-default*, which just sets a value in /boot/grub/default, so that's what you'd need to change (but be careful to only change the entry #).  back to (1): for Grub2 you'd need to alter (2) *grub.cfg* or (3) */boot/grub/grubenv*, but that's less simple (at least in Ubuntu 10.04, *grubenv* seems to save the *label* of the menu entry, not the entry #).